# How to disconnect the stream (Tweepy)?

Tags: twitter, stream, streaming, tweepy

I'm trying to update the stream every 15 minutes to change its rules.
As far as I understand it is impossible to update the filter rules in real time. So I try to stop the stream and then start it again.

```
    class MyStream(tweepy.StreamingClient):    
       def disconnect(self):
    
                self.running=False
    
                print('stop stream)
    
    stream = MyStream(bearer_token=bearer_token, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

stream.disconnect()
```

But it doesn't work. Streaming continues to work.
Can you please tell me how to reallocate what I have in mind?

**update**

I try to add a rule to the stream, then wait 10 seconds and add another one. But it doesn't work. Can you please tell me what the problem is and how to fix it?

```py
    import telebot
    import tweepy
    import time
    bot = telebot.TeleBot()
    api_key = 
    api_key_secret = 
    bearer_token = 
    access_token = 
    access_token_secret = 
    client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, api_key, api_key_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
    auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(api_key, api_key_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    
    
    class MyStream(tweepy.StreamingClient):
        def on_connect(self):
            print('Connected')
    
        def on_response(self, response):
            print(response)
            
    
    stream = MyStream(bearer_token=bearer_token, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
    
    rules = ['book', 'tree', 'word']
    
    #create the stream
    for rule in rules:
        stream.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule(rule))
        print('Showing the rule')
        print(stream.get_rules().data)
        stream.filter(tweet_fields=["referenced_tweets"])
        # this part of the code no longer works.
        print('sleep 10 sec')
        time.sleep(10)
    # this part not working too
    print('Final Streaming Rules:')
    print(stream.get_rules().data)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Twitter API v2 (Tweepy using the `tweepy.client` interface and `StreamingClient` object) the stream does not need to disconnect in order to update the rules, you do that by adding rules via `StreamingClient.add_rules()`. [Docs](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/streaming.html):

> `StreamingClient.add_rules()` can be used to add rules before using `StreamingClient.filter()` to connect to and run a filtered stream:

> `streaming_client.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule("Tweepy"))`
>
> `streaming_client.filter()`
> `StreamingClient.get_rules()` can be used to retrieve existing rules
> and
> `StreamingClient.delete_rules()` can be used to delete rules.

Comment: I have added the code and my comments. Once the streamer has started, no further code is executed and no new rules are added.